# Nested decode statement in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing simple SQL Statement where I need to found my boss's boss. For example if there is three ranks in the column like (lil boss,boss and big boss) and I input lil boss id it need to return the the big boss id. I think that this query must be write white case or decode statements but i have struggles with that. In this code everything would run fine except if I input lil boss ID.Can I use nested decode or case statements? I think that UNION statement would be solution also .
If my table has three column:

| id | status | boss_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | big boss | null |
| 2 | big boss | null |
| 3 | lil boss | 4 |
| 4 | boss | 2 |

If I input 3 it have to return 2

```
      select decode(status,'big boss', id,
                           'boss',boss_id,
                           'lil boss',boss_id)
      from bosses
      where id=123113;
```

Comment: You can nest things, but it's unclear how that would help. It might be useful to include your table definition, sample data, and expected results for several values in your question. Have you perhaps recently been taught about hierarchical queries?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to found my boss's boss

Use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS root_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT status AS root_status,
       id,
       status
FROM   bosses
WHERE  LEVEL = 3
OR     (LEVEL < 3 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1)
START WITH id = 2
CONNECT BY PRIOR boss_id = id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE bosses (id, status, boss_id) AS
SELECT 1, 'big boss', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'big boss', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'lil boss',    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'boss',        2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ROOT_ID | ROOT_STATUS | ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | lil boss | 2 | big boss |

and if you `START WITH id = 2`:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS root_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT status AS root_status,
       id,
       status
FROM   bosses
WHERE  LEVEL = 3
OR     (LEVEL < 3 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1)
START WITH id = 2
CONNECT BY PRIOR boss_id = id;
```

Then it outputs:

| ROOT_ID | ROOT_STATUS | ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | big boss | 2 | big boss |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VkjTw7Cr)

Comment: That does not work, IDK why.

Comment: Also when  I input big boss ID it need to return also big boss id

Comment: i tried to make level dynamic. It depends on what is the status of the input id but when i tried to execute it says this error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: (select case  when status = 'big boss'  then 1
                             when status ='boss' then  2
                             when status ='lil boss' then  3 
                             end as lev
                from bosses) that is the changes

Comment: @ВалентинД. Updated to get lower levels when there is no grandparent row.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come to a solution to this problem. For this purpose I used hierarchical queries and the solution of @MT0. Here is the code that not need to use level. I think it is the best and simpliest solution to the problem. Thanks for helping me!

```
    select id as bossid,
           status as boss_status
    from   bosses b
    where b.status='big boss'
    start with id ='4'
    connect by prior boss_id = id;
```